# Jenkins sourcing a config file during build shell step

Tags: jenkins, sh

I'm trying to set up a build in jenkins that reads a config file generated during a previous build (if it exists) as part of a shell build step. However, the variables I define in the config file don't seem to get put into the environment of the current shell, and I can't figure out why.

The first build step will pull in the config file from the upstream project.

The config file has just simple variable defs:

```
VAR_ONE=foo
VAR_TWO=bar
#etc...
```

The second build step is the shell, which looks like this:

```
if [ -f $WORKSPACE/build_config ];
then
  source $WORKSPACE/build_config

  echo $VAR_ONE
  echo $VAR_TWO
fi
```

In the jenkins console output for the job I see:

```
+ '[' -f /var/lib/hudson-slave/workspace/build_config ']'
+ source /var/lib/hudson-slave/workspace/build_config
++ VAR_ONE=foo
++ VAR_TWO=bar
+ echo

+ echo
```

I don't know what the double plus means, maybe it's being exported into a different scope? If it is, why?

I haven't really looked into the EnvInject or EnvFile plugins yet. I plan to after this exercise in frustration, but I figured this would be a good question to ask anyway since I thought this would be possible to just bash out.

Anyone know what the heck is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark, but have you tried to surround the variables with `{}` like in `${VAR_ONE}` when using them?

About the double plus i just can guess either. I would say it is because of the variables declaration coming from the config file which is loaded into the current shell... But this is really just me guessing.

Hope this helps though.